# score matches scoreb in string using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, highlight

I am trying to highlight matched strings in a div. The issue encountered here is I should be highlighting the string 'score' wherever it occurs in the string. But it matches with the string 'scoreboard' and highlights 'scoreb' string.

```js
var res = $("#div").text();
console.log(res);

var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)score(\\s|<\/span>|$|,|\.)", "ig");

res = res.replace(regex, function(match) {
  match = match.replace(/^\s/g, "");
  match = match.replace(/\s$/g, "");
  return ' <span style="background-color:#bebef8;color:#000;">' + match + '</span> ';
});

console.log(res);
$("#div").html(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div" style="border:1px solid #000" contenteditable="true">
  The total score on the scoreboard is +3 points.
</div>
```

Comment: new RegExp("(^|\\s)score(\\s|<\/span>|$|,|\)", "ig"); I jsut removed the last fullstop and its working don't know how :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're not escaping all the `\` characters in the RegExp string; you missed the last two:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)score(\\s|<\\/span>|$|,|\\.)", "ig");
```

Also note that you can avoid the need to escape them at all by using a Regex literal instead:

```
var regex = /(^|\s)score(\s|<\/span>|$|,|\.)/ig;
```

```js
var res = $("#div").text();
var regex = /(^|\s)score(\s|<\/span>|$|,|\.)/ig;

res = res.replace(regex, function(match) {
  match = match.replace(/^\s/g, "");
  match = match.replace(/\s$/g, "");
  return ' <span style="background-color:#bebef8;color:#000;">' + match + '</span> ';
});
$("#div").html(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div" style="border:1px solid #000" contenteditable="true">
  The total score on the scoreboard is +3 points.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep it simple?

Match any occurance of `score`:

```js
const str = 'The total score on the scoreboard is +3 points.'

document.write(str.replace(/(score)/g, "<span>$1</span>"))
```

```css
span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Match any occurance of `score` surrounded by whitespace:

```js
const str = 'The total score on the scoreboard is +3 points.'

document.write(str.replace(/(\s+)(score)(\s+)/g, "$1<span>$2</span>$3"))
```

```css
span {
  background: yellow;
}
```